The power BI don't show all levels in the dashboard (Azure x odata)
When I use the following command:
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/XXXX/XXX/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State&$filter=WorkItemId%20eq%20431622&$expand=Links($select=SourceWorkItemId,TargetWorkItemId,LinkTypeName)
in the console, it shows many levels, but in Power BI it is limited to just the first level. Do I need to configure something?
Note: I changed the XXX because it was our repository.
I would like to see all levels from Azure in Power BI.
I hope to be able to see all levels of the records, both parents and related, as shown in the browser.
For example, when I put this link in my browser, they show me it:
"value": [
    {
        "WorkItemId": 431622,
        "Title": "PR097  Revisión y actualización de regulados",
        "WorkItemType": "Feature",
        "State": "Analyze",
        "Links": [
            {
                "SourceWorkItemId": 431622,
                "TargetWorkItemId": 414576,
                "LinkTypeName": "Related"
            },
            {
                "SourceWorkItemId": 431622,
                "TargetWorkItemId": 414714,
                "LinkTypeName": "Related"
            },
            {
                "SourceWorkItemId": 431622,
                "TargetWorkItemId": 414762,
                "LinkTypeName": "Related"
            },
            {
                "SourceWorkItemId": 431622,
                "TargetWorkItemId": 414776,
                "LinkTypeName": "Related"
            },
            {
                "SourceWorkItemId": 431622,
                "TargetWorkItemId": 460717,
                "LinkTypeName": "Parent"
            }
        ]
    }
]

}
but, when I put this same link in my power bi, they just show me it


What do you mean about "many levels" and "first level"? Can you provide more details of the problem you are facing, such as the related logs and screenshots?

Since the value of Links is an object list that contains multiple object of linked items. It is not possible to display all the data in a single cell under the Links column.
From the screenshot you provided, can see the Links column is shown as a Table type date column.
You can try to click on "Table" cell to expand the data on a table.

Great!!! It's very simple, but I can't see this option

@robsonZimmermann, Glad that my answer can resolve your question.
